# Passing a complex FormData from angular 5 to Java Spring 3

Tags: javascript, java, spring, angular

I'm trying to insert into a FormData an array of arrays and a string, however java seems to not receive it , I have no log error in my Java server however I have a 500 Internal Server Error in my JavaScript console.

Here is the code for my controller :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/getReporting", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void  getReporting(@RequestParam RecommendationForm form, @RequestParam String type, HttpServletResponse response) throws ApcException {

    System.out.println("prova");
    Map.Entry<String, byte[]> result =  this.reportingService.getReporting(form,type);

    try {
      response.setHeader(//
        "Content-Disposition",//
        "attachment; filename=" +"bobo.xlsx");
      response.setContentType("Application/x");
      response.getOutputStream().write(result.getValue());
      response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IOException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

And here is my service in Angular :

```
 public getExcel(form: FormData): Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>> {

    return this.http.post('/SV-AUD/api/reporting/getReporting', form, {observe: 'response', responseType: 'blob'});
  }
```

And the component where I append the info in the formData :

```
form: FormGroup = this._fb.group(
    {
      hello1: [],
      hello2: [],
      hello3: [],
      hello4: [],
      hello5: [],
      hello6: [],
      hello7: [],
      hello8: [],
      hello9: [],
    }
  );

exportExcel() {

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('form', this.form.getRawValue());

    if (this.detailedType) {
      formData.append('type', 'detailed');
    } else {
      formData.append('type', 'list');
    }
    this.reportingService.getExcel(formData).subscribe(data => {
      const ctHeader = data.headers.get('content-disposition');
      if (ctHeader) {
        const filename = ctHeader.split('=')[1];
        saveAs(data.body, filename);
      }
    });

  }
```

Comment: Have you checked the exact error in logs?

Comment: I have no error in my server logs, in my JavaScript I have a HttpErrorResponse status 500

Answer (score 0):

The behavior that you are describing suggests that Spring is unable to bind your `@RequestParam` parameters of your `getReporting` method to the incoming request.

That means that the data that you are posting from the Angular side does not match up with what is expected on the Spring side.

Unless it's a typo, I'm guessing that the problem is this line in your component's source code, which does nothing (and should be a syntax error due to mis-matched parens):

```
  (this.form.getRawValue()));
```

I'm guessing that it should be :

```
 formData.append('form', (this.form.getRawValue()));
```

Comment: you'll excuse me the correct line is  formData.append('form', this.form.getRawValue()); I don't know why it didn't copied correctly I will try your solution

Comment: I've tried it but it didn't solved the problem, it still gives me 500 internal server error without any log on the server side